# Cannot get the second param in url php

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to get the parameters `c` and `t` of the following url:

```
http://www.sitename.com/index.php?c=hJjB0wf/f4o%26t=4m52Jkm81j8
```

doing `$_GET['c']` and `$_GET['t']` but when i echo the two variables it happens something like this:

```
c=hJjB0wf/f4o%26t=4m52Jkm81j8
t is undefined
```

what is the problem?

Comment: URL paramters are seperated by a `&`  but yours is urlencoded as `%26` so try running the string of your URL through `urldecode()` first

Comment: Not urldecode, but fix whichever place is generating this invalid URL. Fix the root cause, not the symptom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in your url are not `t` param.
In url `%26t` are urlencoded of `&t`
`http://www.sitename.com/index.php?c=hJjB0wf/f4o`**%26**`t=4m52Jkm81j8`.

All you can do is something like

```php
$url = "http://www.sitename.com/index.php?c=hJjB0wf/f4o%26t=4m52Jkm81j8";

$fixed = urldecode($url); // fix %26 -> &

$urlParts = parse_url($fixed);

$params = [];

parse_str($urlParts['query'], $params);

print_R($params);
Array
(
    [c] => hJjB0wf/f4o
    [t] => 4m52Jkm81j8
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the value because the URL is not correct. Before there should be a **`&`** like this, you will get the value of t. Update your URL

```
http://www.sitename.com/index.php?c=hJjB0wf/f4o&t=4m52Jkm81j8
```